# Importing SQL Server Execution Plans in R

Tags: sql-server, r, xml

I am currently trying to import .sqlplan XML files to proces with R code but I am running into some issues.

First of all when I import the .sqlplan file in R I run into an encoding issue:

```
library(XML)
library(readr)

xml_file_raw <- "example.sqlplan"
xml_file <- read_file(xml_file_raw) 
doc <- xmlInternalTreeParse(xml_file)

Document labelled UTF-16 but has UTF-8 content
Error: 1: Document labelled UTF-16 but has UTF-8 content
```

When I supply the encoding to be UTF-16 as configured in the plan XML I get another error:

```
doc <- xmlInternalTreeParse(xml_file, encoding = "UTF-16")
Start tag expected, '<' not found
Error: 1: Start tag expected, '<' not found
```

If I switch to UTF-8 it works

```
doc <- xmlInternalTreeParse(xml_file, encoding = "UTF-8")
```

But if I then want to get the head XML node for instance I notice that the entire XML is inside of it (only added a small bit of the XML in this question)

```
xmlRoot(doc)
<ShowPlanXML xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/07/showplan" Version="1.5" Build="13.0.4435.0">
  <BatchSequence>
    <Batch>
      <Statements>
        <StmtSimple StatementCompId="1" StatementEstRows.....
```

And when I try to retrieve a specific parameter from the XML I always get a NULL result:

```
xpathSApply(doc, "//ns:ShowPlanXML/BatchSequence/Batch/Statements/StmtSimple/@StatementText", xmlValue, namespaces = c(ns = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/07/showplan"))
NULL
```

I uploaded the full .sqlplan XML file here: [example.sqlplan](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Evdlaar/QueryStoreReplay/master/example.sqlplan)

My main goal with this bit of R code is to retrieve various execution plan variables from the exported .sqlplan file itself (like SQL Statement, CPU time, memory grants, etc)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When assigning a prefix to a default namespace, like *ns*, simply apply it to every element of your XPath, not just the first node:

```
library(XML)

data <- readLines("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Evdlaar/QueryStoreReplay/master/example.sqlplan")
doc <- xmlParse(data, asText = TRUE, encoding = "UTF-8")

sql <- xpathSApply(doc, "//ns:ShowPlanXML/ns:BatchSequence/ns:Batch/ns:Statements/ns:StmtSimple/@StatementText", 
                   namespaces = c(ns = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/07/showplan"))

cat(sql)
# Select  
#  p.EnglishProductName,
#  s.SalesAmount,
#  s.UnitPrice,
#  s.DiscountAmount
# from FactResellerSales s
# INNER JOIN DimProduct p on s.ProductKey = p.ProductKey
```